# There is a way to setup videojs (source, etc.) only with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, video.js

Can I setup the player without using `<video>` tag and generate player **only** with JavaScript ?

I spent a lot of time searching for solutions but haven't found an answer.

Comment: So you want to create a player but without the use of `<video>`?  I'm curious to why you would want to do that?

Comment: I want to install player dynamically into the div with special id.
This div is initially empty. In other players has no such disadvantage.

Comment: Do you have some source code for us to work with? Also what have you tried so far? Showing the relevant source code and attempts will give you a better chance of finding a solution...

Comment: There is the setup instruction: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/setup.md
As you can see there is no way to install the player without using `<video>` tag.

Comment: So first you ask "is it possible" now you're telling me it isn't not possible... If you know it isn't possible then I think you'll find you have just answered your own question...

Comment: I wrote that in this instruction, this is not possible. This does not mean that it does not exist. And if you haven't worked with video.js please do not "clever" in the comments.

Comment: Who said I haven't worked with it? I'm just pointing out the fact you have asked if it's possible but in your previous comment you're telling me "As you can see there is no way" **&** I'm recommending you display your attempts so that people will see you have made an attempt of your own rather than expecting others to do the work for you. As you can see not one person has posted, maybe it's because you haven't shown any attempts? I was trying to help you but since you think i'm being "clever" I will help someone else. Good luck!